# Script to migrate unix users and groups

Tags: users, migration

I'm migrating my Ubuntu 8.10 Server to 10.04. Is there any script to migrate users `/etc/passwd` and groups `/etc/group` along with password `/etc/shadow` from one server to another?

Comment: Do you mean migrate the files within the same system that is being upgraded, or to different systems?

Comment: To different system

Answer (score 4):

These files are actually just plain-text files.  You can really move them, copy and paste them, or back them up any way you wish between the systems.

In addition, you might consider some kind of versioning.
A tool like [etckeeper](http://packages.ubuntu.com/etckeeper) [image: Install etckeeper]
 is designed for this.

`apt-cache show etckeeper` :

```
The etckeeper program is a tool to let /etc be stored in a git, mercurial,
bzr or darcs repository.
It hooks into APT to automatically commit changes made to /etc during 
package upgrades. 
It tracks file metadata that version  control systems do not normally support, 
but that is important for /etc, such as the permissions of /etc/shadow. 
It's quite modular and configurable, while also being simple to use if you 
understand the basics of working with version control.
```

If you want to make a simple backup, just use `tar`.

1. `cd /etc`
2. `tar cvfz myfiles.tgz shadow passwd group`

To restore the files, just use tar with 'x' instead of 'c'  :

1. `cd /etc`
2. `tar xvfz myfiles.tgz`

There should be no change in the hash algorithm between these releases.  The system doesn't 'know' your passwords, -- they are calculated as matching or not matching by running the user input through a one-way digest algorithm and comparing the output to the hash in /etc/shadow. It's even conceivable that more than one input will match the stored hash, but you can't go back the other way, so as far as I know, scripting a password export is not possible.

It appears that SHA-512 has been the standard since glibc 2.7, so Ubuntu 8.10 and 10.04 should be completely compatible in this respect.

Comment: Yeah, I know about `etckeeper`. You mean to say just copy paste does the work?

Comment: @user Yes, you can literally copy and paste the files.

Comment: Won't it differ from creating using `adduser` or `useradd`

Comment: When you said 'migrating,' I assumed you meant these users had already been created.  Is that not the case?

Comment: No, the users are present in the old server(8.10) and I've to migrate them to the new(10.04) along with password.

Comment: Unless I'm not understanding what you want, the files are hand-hackable.   You want to copy the password hashes exactly, but there's no magic (other than consistent format of the text fields) otherwise that I know of.

Comment: I would've directly created the users in 10.04 listing from 8.10 but as the password is secret I could not know. If I copy `passwd`, `group`, `shadow` and home directories to new server, and it creates the users and groups then I've no problem!

Comment: I thought there would be something to export and import using the `passwd` file format

Comment: There should be no change in the hash algorithm between these releases -- I don't think this will be a problem.   The system doesn't 'know' your passwords, so there is no way to export them.   They are calculated as matching or not matching by running the user input through a one-way algorithm and comparing the output to the password in /etc/shadow.  It's even conceivable that more than one input will match the stored hash, but you can't go back the other way, so as far as I know, scripting a password export is not possible.